# Varieties isomorphic $\mathrm{mod}\:p$ are diffeomorphic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, differential-topology

If two smooth proper varieties over $\mathbb{Q}$ have isomorphic smooth reductions modulo some prime (for some choice of integral models) are they diffeomorphic after tensoring with $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Serre found examples of surfaces defined over number fields whose homotopy type depends on the embedding of the field into the complex numbers.  This might answer in the negative your question, *after replacing the rational numbers by a number field*.

Comment: @damiano, couldn't one look at an appropriate Weil restriction to reduce the result over a number field to a result over $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: [Serre's example](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k4011c/f1832.item) gives two varieties $X$, $Y$ over the Hilbet class field $K$ of the imaginary quadratic number field $k = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{-23})$ such that $X \cong\ ^\sigma Y$ for some $\sigma \in \operatorname{Gal}(K/k)$, and for a fixed embedding $K \to \mathbf C$ the base changes $X_{\mathbf C}$ and $Y_{\mathbf C}$ are not homotopy equivalent. Reducing modulo a prime $\mathfrak q \subseteq \mathcal O_K$ that is inert in $K/k$ gives isomorphic special fibres (since $\sigma$ fixes $\mathfrak q$), so this gives an example over $K$.

Comment: However, this does not give an example over $\mathbf Q$ via Weil restriction, since the Weil restrictions of conjugate varieties become isomorphic over $\bar{\mathbf Q}$ (hence over $\mathbf C$). Indeed, Weil restriction commutes with arbitrary base change, and for $\operatorname{Spec}(K \otimes_{\mathbf Q} \bar{\mathbf Q}) \cong \coprod \operatorname{Spec} \bar{\mathbf Q} \to \operatorname{Spec} \bar{\mathbf Q}$ corresponds to taking the product of the fibres over each point. Conjugate varieties just correspond to a permutation of the terms.

Comment: Note that under the assumptions of the OP, the $\mathbf Q_\ell$-cohomology algebras of $X(\mathbf C)$ and $Y(\mathbf C)$ are isomorphic for almost all $\ell$. If $X$ and $Y$ are moreover projective, then their rational homotopy types are formal, so $X(\mathbf C)$ and $Y(\mathbf C)$ should be pretty close to being rationally homotopic. This suggests that some intricate integral obstruction as in Serre's construction is needed. (I tried for a bit but couldn't quite come up with an example that works over $\mathbf Q$.)

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn actually formality is true without the projectivity assumption (see Section 6 in DGMS)

Comment: Serre's example is overkill. If you have an element of the class group of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_p)$ that is not 2-torsion, that is, an interesting action of $\mathbb Z/p$ on $\mathbb Z^n$, then just tensor with any elliptic curve $E$ defined over $\mathbb Q$. This gives an action of $\mathbb Z/p$ on $E^n$ which represents twice the original element in the class group. Then form an $E^n$ bundle over the Godeaux-Serre variety. This gives several varieties that are not homotopy equivalent, but whose $\ell$-adic homotopy types are. But are their mod $\ell$ reductions isomorphic? Probably.

Comment: A few follow-ups on my proposal. I should talk of the class group of $\mathbb Z[\mathbb Z/n]$, which is related to the class group of $\mathbb Z[\mathbb \zeta_n]$, but not, I think, always isomorphic. For the varieties to be isomorphic, we must have the class be 4-torsion, the elliptic curve supersingular, and the isomorphism not over $\mathbb F_p$, but $\mathbb F_{p^2}$. I am not sure that those hypotheses are enough and maybe the class and curve must be chosen carefully, if it is even possible.